# Cannot downgrade from .NET 4.7.2 back to .NET 4.7

Tags: .net

I'm on Windows Server 2016 and I need to downgrade from .NET 4.7.2 (installed developer pack, not just framework) back to .NET 4.7. You'd think this would be easy, but it seems impossible:

1. The .NET installer will not allow an older version of .NET to be installed.
2. I uninstalled .NET 4.7.2 completely (and even rebooted), but the .NET installer mistakenly believes that 4.7.2 is still on there, and thus won't allow me to install 4.7.
3. The only version of .NET currently on the server is 4.6, and it's just the framework (not dev pack).

[image]

Is there a registry key I can change/delete so that the .NET installer will allow me to install .NET 4.7?

Comment: The developer pack allows you to target an older .NET version that you don't have installed anymore.  It is about what the user of your program needs to have available.  Do *not* run the framework installer.  If you don't have the developer pack for 4.7 for some odd reason then [look here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks).

Comment: Well, you'll need it either way to restore the dev pack back for 4.7.2

Comment: Hans, your solution solved it. The framework installer was the problem. Can you post that as the answer?